# How to use Bitnami Wordpress Install on XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: xampp, bitnami

I'm new to running Xampp and Bitnami, but as far I can tell Bitnami provides a 1-click install facility for Wordpress similar to the facility I get on my web host.

Xampp is running and I've installed Bitnami at `C:\xampp` and can see this under the Applications item on Xampp Admin, but I can't see how to install Wordpress on a new site.

I've tried running the installer again and using path `C:\xampp\htdocs\my_new_site` and I get an `error` saying it doesn't contain a `valid XAMPP installation`. How should I be using Bitnami?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BitNami for XAMPP installs the application you select (WordPress, Drupal and/or Joomla!) in the C:\XAMPP\apps directory here is the [step by step guide](http://bitnami.com/stack/xampp). If you run the installer and selected WordPress, the files should be placed in c:\XAMPP\apps\wordpress. Currently With the BitNami installer you will be able to install only one WordPress (you can add more instances manually though).

Comment: That's about as far as I got but I'm not really understanding the purpose of installing BitNami and what I do next with it. I was thinking I'd be able to do a one-click install of Wordpress for new sites I set up in XAMPP. Am I missing the point perhaps?

Comment: With BitNami for XAMPP you can do one once-click install of WordPress. In the future we plan to support different WordPress installations. Currently BitNami has other options like the full WordPress stack which will install as many WordPress as you want each one with its own Apache and MySQL server. In that case each installation is completely independent from others. http://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress.

Comment: @kaysa Please prove me wrong but it seems that there is still no multiplage wp for xampp

Comment: On OS X, it's slightly different: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress`. Also to note is that the htdocs directory is restricted, so if you want to manually add content files after installation, you'll need to adjust the directory permissions.